# React js and bootstrap modal from examples on github

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, reactjs

I'm trying to set up an app with react and everything is going well except for my modal. I've used this code from the following link, untouched and I get errors. https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/examples/jquery-bootstrap/js/app.js

Try this fiddle http://jsbin.com/eGocaZa/1/edit?html,css,output

The callback functions don't seem to have access to "this". If you log "this" in the console, it logs the window object.

```
openModal: function() {
  this.refs.modal.open();
},
```

I did pass in this and return a new function which seemed to work but that didn't seem right and not playing nice with jsfiddle. I got the modal firing locally but then I run into the same issue with the close function. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
var Example = React.createClass({
  handleCancel: function() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel?')) {
      this.refs.modal.close();
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    var modal = null;
    modal = (
      <BootstrapModal
        ref="modal"
        confirm="OK"
        cancel="Cancel"
        onCancel={this.handleCancel}
        onConfirm={this.closeModal}
        title="Hello, Bootstrap!">
        This is a React component powered by jQuery and Bootstrap!
      </BootstrapModal>
    );
    return (
      <div className="example">
          {modal}
        <BootstrapButton onClick={this.openModal(this)}>Open modal</BootstrapButton>
      </div>
    );
  },

  openModal: function(obj) {
    return function(){obj.refs.modal.open();}
  },

  closeModal: function() {
    this.refs.modal.close();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a few problems with your code:

1. You were loading the Bootstrap JS before jQuery but it needs to be loaded after.
2. You were using React 0.3.0, which had different scoping rules for component methods -- since React 0.4, methods are [bound to the component automatically](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/07/02/react-v0-4-autobind-by-default.html). You could have written `openModal: React.autoBind(function() { this.refs.modal.open(); })` or `onClick={this.openModal.bind(this)}` in React 0.3 but upgrading to 0.4 removes the necessity to bind manually.
3. Your modal had the `hide` class which seemed to make it invisible; I removed it and now the modal seems to appear. I'm not sure at the moment why this behaves differently between your code and the example.

Here's my working example [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/eGocaZa/5/edit) . The modal appears to have some strange CSS applied to it but I don't think it's React-related so I'll leave you here. Let me know if anything's unclear.

Comment: I changed the bootstrap version to work with the example code. Thanks for the help. Upgrading to .4 worked out perfectly http://jsbin.com/eGocaZa/7/

Answer (score 2):

Of course I worked on this all night and then figure the answer out after I ask a question here but here's the solution.

The functions needed to be wrapped in the autoBind to access "this". Here are the functions affected...

```
    close: React.autoBind(function() {console.log(this);
    $(this.getDOMNode()).modal('hide');
}),
open: React.autoBind(function() {
    $(this.getDOMNode()).modal('show');
}),
...
handleCancel: React.autoBind(function() {
    if (this.props.onCancel) {
        this.props.onCancel();
    }
}),
handleConfirm:React.autoBind(function() {
    if (this.props.onConfirm) {
        this.props.onConfirm();
    }
})
...
openModal: React.autoBind(function() {
    this.refs.modal.open();
}),
closeModal: React.autoBind(function() {
        this.refs.modal.close();
})
```

Comment: As noted in one of the other answers: React 0.4.0+ autoBinds all functions by default http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/07/02/react-v0-4-autobind-by-default.html.